only one object Glitching in viewport and blurry in render
There are 3 product objects, container,, pump bottle and oil bottle. In viewport shader the pump bottle is glitching on the top and under the bottom of the bottle. In the render the pump bottle only is rendering with a line in the middle with some blurriness. The other object is not having this issue. There are no modifiers on the pump bottle.



That first image is showing classic signs of Z-fighting due to overlapping faces. Are you sure that you don't have duplicate objects in the same place?
